# What do I use to convert string into unicode

Tags: c#, string, unicode, console.readline

I am having an issue with this block of code.

```
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        string PlayerName = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(PlayerName);
```

What I'm trying to do is get the computer to read the name you input, and ask you if that is your name. Directly after I type my name though there is an exception. Convert.ToInt32 isn't what I'm supposed to use, and I guess my question is what do I put there instead.

I am new to programming and I'm not even sure if it's called unicode. Sorry.

Comment: Do you want to know how unicode string is represented in bytes?

Answer (score 2):

Console.ReadLine() will return a string, no need to do any conversions:

```
    Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
    string PlayerName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(PlayerName);
```

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`Convert.ToInt32()` throw casting error if you do not pass valid integer value inside it. So, you need to check it gracefully and get interger value. For that, you can `Int32.TryParse(input, out val)` and get integer value.

Ex :

```
int value;
if(Int32.TryParse(your_input, out value))
{
// if pass condition, then your input is integer and can use accordingly
}
```

So, your program will be like this if you want to print integer value only :

```
    Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
    var value = Console.ReadLine();
    int intVal;
    if(Int32.TryParse(value, out intVal))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(intVal);
    }
```

If you want only to print what you've got from ReadLine method, you can just have :

```
  Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
  Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Convert.ToInt32(String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) "Converts the specified string representation of a number to an equivalent 32-bit signed integer".  You are getting an error because you are not typing in an integer value in your console.

Your `PlayerName` variable is of type `string`, and the return value of `Console.ReadLine()` is already a `string`, so you don't need any conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re dealing with Unicode characters, you might have to set proper encoding like so

```
Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
string PlayerName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(PlayerName);
```